# Configuring launch agent on mac os to start mongo db fails with an obscure socket error

Tags: macos, mongodb, launchd

After installing mongodb using homebrew, and following the information that homebrew provided, I did the following:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
```

But got the following error:

```
Bug: launchctl.c:2406 (25182):13: (dbfd = open(g_job_overrides_db_path, O_RDONLY | O_EXLOCK | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) != -1 
launch_msg(): Socket is not connected
```

Starting a mongodb process in the terminal works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By any chance were you using tmux? I came across this discussion of a similar bug under iTerm2 issues which proposes that tmux might interfere with the sockets. I also read somewhere else confirming the same behavior.

http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=997

Comment: Ahh yes, it was tmux. Thanks for letting me know!